# jmeter: Can I use jmeter JMeter "JMS Point-To-Point" to send messages to MSFT Azure Service Bus queue?

Tags: jmeter, jms

I have xml messages and want to send them to an MSFT ASB queue.

Is it doable with JMeter *JMS Point-To-Point*?

If yes How?
Cannot figure out how to configure.
All I have is a connection String to the ASB.

Thanks in advance.

---

#### Feedback 1:

```
INFO o.a.q.j.s.SaslMechanismFinder: Best match for SASL auth was: SASL-ANONYMOUS
2018-10-02 18:46:19,734 INFO o.a.q.j.JmsConnection: Connection ID::8356a2a7-4cf2-4ab0-8ee9-240b62f5fd73:1 connected to remote Broker: amqps://<HOSTNAME>.servicebus.windows.net
2018-10-02 18:46:20,321 WARN o.a.q.j.p.a.b.AmqpResourceBuilder: Open of resource:(JmsProducerInfo { ID::8356a2a7-4cf2-4ab0-8ee9-240b62f5fd73:1:1:1, destination = <QUEUENAME> }) failed: Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://<HOSTNAME>.servicebus.windows.net/<QUEUENAME>'. TrackingId:79fda5972c644c8d8f1c33bea40987ae_G52, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:10/2/2018 3:46:17 PM [condition = amqp:unauthorized-access]
2018-10-02 18:46:20,321 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JMSSampler: Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://<HOSTNAME>.servicebus.windows.net/<QUEUENAME>'. TrackingId:79fda5972c644c8d8f1c33bea40987ae_G52, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:10/2/2018 3:46:17 PM [condition = amqp:unauthorized-access]
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://<HOSTNAME>.servicebus.windows.net/<QUEUENAME>'. TrackingId:79fda5972c644c8d8f1c33bea40987ae_G52, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:10/2/2018 3:46:17 PM [condition = amqp:unauthorized-access]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be possible through [AMQP JMS Client](https://qpid.apache.org/download.html) library

Steps:

- Add those 2 jars to jmeter/lib folder

  - geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.0.jar
  - qpid-jms-client-[version].jar
- Create a properties file called servicebus.properties:

  ```
  # servicebus.properties - sample JNDI configuration

  # Register a ConnectionFactory in JNDI using the form:
  # connectionfactory.[jndi_name] = [ConnectionURL]
  connectionfactory.SBCF = amqps://[SASPolicyName]:[SASPolicyKey]@[namespace].servicebus.windows.net

  # Register some queues in JNDI using the form
  # queue.[jndi_name] = [physical_name]
  # topic.[jndi_name] = [physical_name]
  queue.QUEUE = queue1
  ```

Configure [JMS Point-to-Point](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point) this way (change host):

[image: JMS Point-to-Point config]

See this for more details:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
did everything you listed above and am one step closer.


Check Feedback 1 in original posting.

Don't get this. 
What should be done here ?

Comment: you don’t have enough rights to send to queue, check azure configuration

Answer (score 0):

I could achive sending message to azure service bus by using the "AMQP Publisher-Sampler" or "Java Sampler". The difference to JMS Point-to-point Sampler is that both use "SEND claims" resp. "LISTEN claims", when sending a message, and that is not part of JMS Point to Point standard implementation.